# Auth0 Authorization Code Grant with NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, auth0, nestjs

I'm looking for an example of how to implement the [Authorization Code Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant) flow of Auth0 using NestJS.

Answer (score 4):

In order to create a `POST` endpoint `/authenticate` on the backend which handles the [exchange of the Authorization Code for an Access Token](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant#2-exchange-the-authorization-code-for-an-access-token), we need to first define the [dto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that the endpoint expects.

From the client we expect an object having the `authorization_code` and the `origin` fields.

**authorization-request.dto.ts**

```
export class AuthorizationRequestDto {
  readonly authorization_code: string;
  readonly origin: string;
}
```

Now we can create a [controller](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers) which will handle the `POST` requests sent to `/authenticate`:

```
import { Body, Controller, HttpService, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosResponse } from '@nestjs/common/http/interfaces/axios.interfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthorizationRequestDto } from './authorization-request.dto';

@Controller('authenticate')
export class AuthController {

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  @Post()
  authenticate(@Body() authorizationRequestDto: AuthorizationRequestDto): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.post('https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token', {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
      code: authorizationRequestDto.authorization_code,
      redirect_uri: authorizationRequestDto.origin,
    }).pipe(
      map(response => response.data),
    );
  }
}
```

Naturally, int the above code we need to replace `YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN`, `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` and `YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET`.